# CORS Issue with Pannellum JS connecting to Azure BLOB MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, cors, azure-blob-storage

I am using Pannellum js to display images in my MVC app. Currently I am using local file server for storing images and displaying the same. Now I have moved all images to Azure BLOB Container.

The issue is I am getting CORS error while retrieving image from blob:

[image]

I have checked many solution on net. But none of them is working is my case. I have Set global CORS rules for XMLHttpRequest using "createCORSRequest" but not working. I have also set `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />` in config and Set `AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute` for my method.

For reference, my BLOB URL, https://inspecttv.blob.core.windows.net and my site is  https://www.inspectanytime.tv/

Below is the code from where I am passing BLOB image to Json and in a way to JavaScript.

```
string Json = "[";
                    string Photos = "";
                    //string SiteUrl = "http://inspectanytime.azurewebsites.net";

                    foreach (tblAT_PropertyImage tbl in LST)
                    {
                        string thumbimage = tbl.Photo.ToString().Substring(0, tbl.Photo.ToString().LastIndexOf('.')) + "_thumb" + tbl.Photo.ToString().Substring(tbl.Photo.ToString().LastIndexOf('.'));
                        string FullImage = AzureCloud.GetFileFromCloud(tbl.Photo, AzureCloud.AzureContainers.inspectimagefiles); // SiteUrl + "/ViewerImage.ashx?p=" + tbl.Photo;

                        string Thumb = AzureCloud.GetFileFromCloud(thumbimage, AzureCloud.AzureContainers.inspectimagefiles); //SiteUrl + "/ViewerThumb.ashx?p=" + tbl.Photo;
                        string SinglePhoto = "{\"image\":\"" + FullImage + "\",\"imageThumb\":\"" + Thumb + "\",\"description\":\"" + tbl.Tag + "\",\"Address\":\"" + Address + "\"}";
                        if (Photos != "")
                        {
                            Photos += "," + SinglePhoto;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Photos += SinglePhoto;
                        }
                    }
                    Json += Photos;
                    Json += "]";
```

Comment: Pro tip: asking for urgency is a good way to get downvotes, don't do it! Please [read this community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495).

Comment: Are you assembling JSON manually? There should be a library in asp.net to do that for you - can you swap to that?

Comment: @halfer I am using 'https://github.com/mpetroff/pannellum' , This JSON code was working for sending data to that JS for local files ( i will check with your suggestion, too) , this comes in picture with BLOB url.

Comment: I think main issue is 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is not reflecting for this action (XMLHttpRequest) only. Please suggest alternatives

Comment: If you suspect cross-site issues, have you confirmed that in your browser's developer console?

Comment: Just Attached Image referencing console

Comment: Didn't see your reply, please get into the habit of using `@halfer` or whatever handle here, to notify people! OK, so have you searched for the name of this library and the text of the error? Maybe someone has experienced this before.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with CORS. This article from Mozilla, enumerates and explains CORS implementation in depth.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

If this is not a production site you could use https://crossorigin.me/

Just replace http: //someurl/panorama.jpg with https: //crossorigin.me/http: //someurl/panorama.jpg

Comment: Don't provide a link. Use it as reference.